# Why is initstate not being called here on screen load

Tags: flutter, dart

I don't understand why it's not working any explanation welcome, I'm trying to call the initstate when it is loaded from navigation.pushed  => MapPagePermissions()

The widget loads but the innitstate doesn't get called.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class MapPagePermissions extends StatefulWidget {
  const MapPagePermissions({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MapPagePermissionsState createState() => _MapPagePermissionsState();
}

class _MapPagePermissionsState extends State<MapPagePermissions> {

  @override
  void initstate(){
    super.initState();
    print('Innit State');
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print('Build Function'); // Prints

    return const Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Text(
          'MAP PAGE',
          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 30),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: You have a typo, `initstate` should be `initState`.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry it's been a long day,

spelling in initState